# Seq logging server not accessible behind nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, vps, datalust-seq

I have a seq server installed on a windows server 2022 vps, i have also nginx set as a reverse proxy for "MyApp" and the "Seq" server, no load balancing configured, just reverse proxying.

The probleme:
When i try to access seq server ui from h t t p : / / l o c a l h o s t : /seq/ it works perfectly, no issues, but when i try to access it from  an external machine using my VPS ip it gives me, "Bad Request - Invalid Hostname HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid."
It's worth noting that "MyApp" (an asp.ner core app) is perfectly working when i access it from external machine (h t t p : / / xx.xx.xx.xx : 80 /MyApp/), this means that nginx is correctly working and configured for MyApp.

On my vps, nginx/logs/error.txt:

```
2023/08/22 09:04:15 [error] 3064#1044: *7 connect() failed (10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: xx.xx.xx.xx, request: "GET /seq/seq-ui2-tpl-1690501959253.min.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5005/seq-ui2-tpl-1690501959253.min.js", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/seq/"
2023/08/22 09:04:15 [warn] 3064#1044: *7 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: xx.xx.xx.xx, request: "GET /seq/seq-ui2-tpl-1690501959253.min.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5005/seq-ui2-tpl-1690501959253.min.js", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/seq/"
```

My set up:

1. Seq is running as a service.
2. Seq.exe is allowed to recieve inbound connexions on it's functionning port (5005 in my case)
3. Seq config:

I tried many nginx configurations that i found, but none works, i also tried to configure seq server, i set api.canonicalURI to  h t t p : / / l o c a l h o s t, and api.ingestionPorts to 5005, but nothing works.

```
api.canonicalUri=
api.corsAllowedOrigins=
api.frameAncestors=
api.hardSessionExpirySeconds=
api.hstsIncludeSubDomains=False
api.hstsMaxAge=31536000
api.idleSessionExpirySeconds=172800
api.ingestionPort=
api.ingestionPorts=
api.integratedAuthenticationScheme=
api.listenUris=h t t p : / / l o c a l h o s t : 5005
api.minRequestBodyDataRateBytesPerSecond=240
api.minRequestBodyDataRateGracePeriodMilliseconds=5000
api.redirectHttpToHttps=False
api.webServer=
appHost.executionPolicy=
appHost.installPolicy=
audit.auditPath=
audit.auditServerApiKey=
audit.auditServerUrl=
certificates.certificatesPath=
certificates.defaultPassword=
diagnostics.internalLoggingLevel=Information
diagnostics.internalLogPath=C:\ProgramData\Seq\Logs
diagnostics.internalLogServerApiKey=
diagnostics.internalLogServerUrl=
diagnostics.metricsSamplingIntervalSeconds=300
diagnostics.nativeStorageMetricsSamplingIntervalMinutes=60
diagnostics.telemetryServerUrl=
features.enabled=
firstRun.adminPasswordHash=QLfTt06s...
firstRun.adminUsername=admin
firstRun.requireAuthenticationForHttpIngestion=False
metastore.msSql.connectionString=
metastore.msSql.msiResource=
metastore.msSql.msiTenantId=
metastore.msSql.schema=
metastore.postgres.connectionString=
metastore.postgres.schema=
process.workingSetLimitBytes=
secretKey.provider=
secretKey.providerArgs=
services.servicesBaseUri=
storage.disableFreeDiskSpaceChecking=False
storage.flare.concurrentReaderLimit=
storage.flare.indexerPriority=0
storage.flare.readerParallelismLimit=
storage.maximumFutureTimestampDriftSeconds=3420
storage.secretKey=pmk.AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE.....
```

4. Nginx config file:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;
error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  logs/error.log  info;
#pid        logs\\nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  xx.xx.xx.xx; #my actual vps ip adress here

        #charset koi8-r;

        access_log  logs/host.access.log;

        location /seq/ {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            rewrite /seq/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass h t t p : / / l o c a l h o s t : :5005;
            proxy_read_timeout 90;
        }

        location /my_app/ {
            proxy_pass         h t t p : / / l o c a l h o s t : 5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            #proxy_read_timeout 300;
            #proxy_connect_timeout 300;
            #proxy_send_timeout 300;
        }


        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```